# derivatives of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Prove by induction that the derivative of a polynomial of odd degree is a polynomial of even degree.

That is, I have the following polynomial of odd degree

$$P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots+a_nx^n$$

Then its first derivative is

$$P'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots+na_nx^{n-1}$$

¿how would you prove that $P'(x)$ is even degree?

Now, your second derivative would be

$$P''(x)=2a_2+6a_3x+\cdots+n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$

How would you prove that $P''(x)$ is of odd degree?

Comment: If $p(x)$ is of odd degree, then $n=2k+1$ for some $k$.  What does that tell us about $n-1$?  What about $n-2$?

Comment: @Ryan $n-1=(2k+1)-1=2k$ then $n-1$ indicates that the polynomial is even degree, Likewise $n-2=(2k+1)-2=2k-1$ which indicates that it is of odd degree, could you help me to prove it in the polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't have to use induction. Suppose $k$ is some odd integer such that $P_k(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+a_kx^k$, a polynomial of degree $k$. Since $k$ is odd, $k=2n+1$ for some integer $n$. Taking the derivative using the power rule, we see that $P_k'(x)=a_1+a_2x+\ldots+a_{k-1}x^{k-2}+a_kx^{k-1}$. Since $k$ was the degree of $P_k$ and taking the derivative simply reduced all the exponents of $x$ by $1$, we see that $P_k'$ has degree $k-1$. Since $k-1=(2n+1)-1=2n$, we see that $P_k'$ must have degree $2n$, so $P_k'$ must have an even degree.

You can use similar reasoning for $P_k''$, just noting the degree of $P_k''$ will be $k-2$ due to the power rule.

Comment: THANKKKKKSSSS =)